Asymptotic form of wavefunctions in case of $k$ one-dimensional asymptotic regions
I'm reading the paper Hamiltonian Truncation Study of Supersymmetric
Quantum Mechanics, and am struggling to understand some things about section 2. In particular eqn 2.2, and how to think about the scattering process being described.
The section begins: Let us consider a quantum mechanical system with k one-dimensional asymptotic regions, where the dispersion relation takes the form $E = p^2$, $p$ being the asymptotic momentum. The in and out states will be denoted $|E, i \rangle^{\text{in}}$ and $|E, i \rangle^{\text{out}}$ respectively, $i = 1,2, ..., k$. They are related by the S-matrix:
\begin{align*}
    |E, i\rangle^{\text{in}} &= \sum_j S_{ij}(E)|E, j\rangle^{\text{out}},
\end{align*}
where $S_{ij}(E)$ is a $k \times k$ unitary matrix. An asymptotic wave function takes the form
\begin{align*}
    \sum_i\left(a_i e^{-ipx} + e^{ipx}\sum_ja_jS_{ji} \right) |i\rangle.
\end{align*}
My question is how to think about the wavefunction in this case, and also how they got this expression for the asymptotic wavefunctions.
The scattering I have seen before was undergrad quantum, and we did 1d and 3d cases (see MITx online courses 8.04 and 8.06).
I think the intuition here is that we picture some (?3d) potentional, that has value zero (or close to zero) along certain directions going radially outwards from the center. We can imagine sending a particle (or energy eigenstate) inwards along a particular such valley, towards the center. We then get back outward going waves flowing outward along all k valleys (including the one we chose to send a particle inwards along). And maybe for the general such solution, they are doing some superposition of k ingoing with k outgoing states. But I don't see how they arrive at the specific expression.
I also a bit confused as to why we are using the full coordinate range for x, and I am very confused why x is being used as a coordinate for all of the valleys. And if we were to write the full wavefunction, what would it be a function of? And what is $|i\rangle$ supposed to be? $|E, i\rangle^{\text{out}}$?
If someone could give some clarification about the setup and how to understand and think about the given asymptotic form, I would appreciate it.

The system they are describing is a mathematical abstraction where you have $k$ different channels in one dimension along which a plane wave can arrive to the system, and thus also $k$ channels along which they can leave. Your valley picture might be an approximate implementation of such a system, but for the sake of the math, it might be easier just to think of it as abstract "channels", and remember that this might be an approximate description of a number of systems.
Here is a quick derivation of the equation - there might be some details I have missed, but the main ideas you need should be there:
To arrive at the equation, we note that a state is specified by two quantum numbers, the energy $E$ and the channel $i$, i.e. it lives in the product Hilbert space of those two Hilbert spaces, and $|E,i\rangle = |E\rangle \otimes |i\rangle$. Furthermore, due to the dispersion relation $E=p^2$, we can change the energy quantum number to a momentum quantum number to write a state in the basis $|p\rangle \otimes |i\rangle$.
We can then define the general single-channel asymptotic wave function in position space at a fixed energy (and thus a fixed squared momentum) as the plane wave states
$$\psi_{E}(x) = \langle x | E \rangle = \langle x | -p \rangle + \langle x | p \rangle = e^{-ipx} + e^{i p x}.$$
Note that we include both negative and positive momentum, corresponding to ingoing and outgoing waves, respectively.
This wave function describes what is going on in a single channel $i$ at fixed energy. A state with fixed energy but which is allowed to exist in more channels will be a linear combination of channels,
$$|\psi_E(x)\rangle = \sum_i a_i \langle x|E\rangle\otimes |i\rangle$$
Since we are considering a scattering event, the incoming and outgoing waves must be allowed separate coefficients, yielding
$$|\psi_E(x)\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i \langle x|-p\rangle |i\rangle + \sum_{i=1}^k b_i \langle x|p\rangle |i\rangle $$
Using our result from above, this becomes
$$|\psi_E(x)\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i e^{-ipx} |i\rangle + \sum_{j=1}^k b_j e^{ipx} |j\rangle $$
The coefficients $a_i = \langle i^\text{in} | \psi \rangle$ and $b_i = \langle i^\text{out} | \psi \rangle$ are related by the S matrix as
$$b_i = \langle i^\text{out} | \psi \rangle = \sum_j \langle j^\text{in} | S_{ji} | \psi\rangle = \sum_j S_{ji}  \langle j^\text{in} | \psi\rangle = \sum_j S_{ji} a_j$$
Note that we have used the fact that $S$ is unitary due to time reversal symmetry. We then have
$$|\psi_E(x)\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i e^{-ipx} |i\rangle + \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k a_j S_{ji}  e^{ipx}|i\rangle,$$
which should be the result you are looking for.

Thanks, but 1. The "px" in the exponents doesn't seem right. Assuming the wavefunction is a function of n coordinates, then shouldn't "px" be replaced by $\vec{p}_i \cdot \vec{x}$, where $\vec{p}_i = p\hat{p}_i$, where $\hat{p}_i$ points radially out along the ith channel? 2. Where did $\vec{a} = S\vec{b}$ come from?


The paper appears to assume that the $k$ different channels exist in one dimension, and so only one coordinate is required. Somewhat confusing and hard to picture, but the math holds. This is probably equivalent to a full 3D treatment. 2. I have edited my answer to not include vectors, hopefully it is clearer now.


Thanks, this is helpful. But I still don't understand how that "px" makes sense here, nor what is wrong in my above comment about it.

I mean, if you write the Hilbert space as a tensor product of the 1d wavefunctions with some number of "channels", as you did, then I think I follow. But it's not clear to me that that was a valid move. I thought we were looking for some wavefunction of several variables (x1, x2, ...) and that the potential (that is defined on the same R^n as the wavefunction) has some "flat directions".

And I think what I'm saying is constent with their 2d example in section 4.

And is x assumed positive in your argument?

No, $x$ is not assumed positive. If you want to model a scattering system of $k$ channels only existing in one dimension, then the asymptotic plane wave states are $e^{ipx}$. Whether that is an accurate description or not depends on your physical system. But if you want to arrive at the equation in your question, you must assume $k$ channels in one dimension. You might find that this is ultimately equivalent to something with more dimensions, but that is a different question. It might be that they use the 1D model as a simple case to introduce the method.

How do you know x is not assumed positive?

I did not assume $x$ to be positive in my derivation, and did not have to in order to arrive at the result. I did not see any such assumption being made in the paper you linked, either, and I am not familiar with it being a convention in scattering. But if they write somewhere that they assume $x$ positive, then that is what they do.

x > 0 is assumed in the analysis of 1d scattering covered in the MIT 8.04 course online. I believe this is to make it serve as a better prep for the analysis in 3d, where we have r > 0. Seeing as in this paper's case, I thought we had the setup I've described above with a wavefunction and potential as functions on R^n, it seemed that the 1d coordinate for any particular flay direction would be more like a radius, and so positive.

@Gleeson If this answer was helpful, please consider upvoting it, marking it as correct and giving it the bounty.

Apologies I was too slow
